# Anylogic restricted area limits cause error and show -1 still inside the limit when the model crashes

Tags: limit, area, anylogic

This model runs by injecting products via a button that get sent to rooms USP1 and USP2. There is a fleet of transporters that carry the product to the next room by moveByTransporters as well as the logic that moves the product through the equipment by delays and seize/releases. The logic for USP1 and USP2 both move the product to the same Harvest room  after their logic is complete.
The model randomly chooses which USP room to go to and when it goes through the USP2 logic there are no errors. By injecting a second product both USP1 and USP2's logic have a product moving through and meet at this Harvest logic. 
When I run the model it works until there are multiple products and the error occurs. Looking at the restricted limits for USP1 I see a -1 still inside the limit.

[[image: USP1 and USP2 Logic]

[image: Harvest Logic]

[image: Error Image]

Comment: sorry, which RestrictedAreaIn that USP1LimitOut is linked to?

Comment: It's the second line of logic, first block, of the USP1 grey box with all its logic inside. Called USP1LimitIn and there is also a -1 shown inside

Answer (score 0):

well, somewhere within the RestrictedArea, you are letting additional agents "slip in" without registering them into the RestrictedArea.

One candidate is the weird "split2" that folds splitted agents back into the subsequent elements. This creates new agents within your RestrictedArea without them registering properly.

You cannot create new agents within a RestrictedArea as it will not notice that, see the [help](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2F_ProcessModeling%2FRestrictedAreaStart.html&resultof=%22%72%65%73%74%72%69%63%74%65%64%22%20%22%72%65%73%74%72%69%63%74%22%20%22%61%72%65%61%22%20)